# React - Too many re-renders after adding onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and i'm playing with a very simple site that fetches data from a pokemon api.

[image: Image of the site - screenshot]

I wanted to add an onClick event on my list items to change the css when it's clicked. But
when i add setExpand(!expand) to my list item like this `<Li onClick={setExpand(!expand)}>` i get an error telling me "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" that i can't make sense of.

## Main

```
//Styling
const Section = styled.section`
  margin-top: 100px;
`;

const Ul = styled.ul`
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

const Main = styled.main`
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
`;

export default function Test() {
  //States
  const [pokemonArray, newPokemon] = useState([]);

  //Hooks
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const dataArray = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        let data = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + i).then(res => res.json());
        dataArray.push(data);
      }

      newPokemon(dataArray);
    })()
  }, []);

  //Render
  return (
    <Route exact path="/test">
      <Main>
        <Section>
          <Ul>
            {articleTemplate()}
          </Ul>
        </Section>
      </Main>
    </Route>
  );

  //Functions
  function articleTemplate() {
    const components = []
    pokemonArray.forEach((elm, index) => {
      components.push(<Li key={index} src={elm.sprites.front_default} />)
    })
    return components;
  };
}
```

## List item component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Li = styled.li`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:url('https://via.placeholder.com/500x500');
`;

const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;

export default function Image(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Li onClick={setExpand(!expand)}>
      <Img src={props.src} />
    </Li>
  )
}
```

Comment: `<Li onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>`

Comment: the comment above is your solution - without the wrapping function react will always execute the `setExpand` everytime on render since it is a function call. this will cause a re-render and once the script arrives there again, it will again call that method, cause another re-render and so on....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a callback instead of executing the code inside `onClick`

```js
<Li onClick={() => setExpand(exp => !exp)}>
   <Img src={props.src} />
</Li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `handleClick` function

```
export default function Image(props) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const handleClick=()=>{
   setExpand(!expand);
  }
  return (
    <Li onClick={handleClick}>
      <Img src={props.src} />
    </Li>
  )
}
```